# Google Books API (Related Books)

Tags: google-books

I've been skimming over the Google Books API, but couldn't find anything that could retrieve a list of related books.

There's a related books carousel shown on their [Google books pages](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=ljWL5A7D2JAC&dq=the%20hobbit&hl=en&sa=X&ei=siL8VMu-OYyB8QXWooDoAw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA).

Comment: A bit late but you could use [retrofit] (https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and the [google books api docs] (https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#PerformingSearch)